# DocFx: how to suppress certain info about type (inheritance, constructors, assembly etc)

Tags: docfx

I am using DocFx to generate documentation about a WCF web-service. The target audience for the documentation is clients of the web-service. These clients obviously do not have access to the .NET binaries directly.

Documentation of the public interfaces and models, and their methods and properties, is important, but there is a lot of other information that is irrelevant to clients:

- Implements
- Inherited Members
- Assembly
- Syntax
- Constructors

To be clear - I am not wanting to filter out certain types or members (as described [here](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/howto_filter_out_unwanted_apis_attributes.html)) - I am wanting to filter out entire sections of the documentation of all types.

Answer (score 6):

You can customize the output by overwriting the template.

In my case, I erased the `assembly` section from the class page by following.

1. export default template by `docfx template export default`.
2. copy `_exported_templates/default/partials/class.header.tmpl.partial` into `DOCFX_PROJECT_ROOT/templates/custom/partial`.
3. edit and remove the assembly section from the copied file.
4. in your `build` section of `docfx.json`, edit the `template` to the following

```
"template": [
      "default",
      "templates/custom"
    ],
```

You can now build normally by something like `docfx docfx.json`.

I believe the other sections you mentioned can be erased by editing and copying the appropriate files in the template directory.

Comment: This was really helpful thank you. One minor thing though, I needed to change `DOCFX_PROJECT_ROOT/templates/custom/partial` to `DOCFX_PROJECT_ROOT/templates/custom/partials` (s on the end)

Answer (score 2):

How to hide inherited members:

Add

```
.inheritedMembers { display: none; }
```

to "_site\styles\main.css"